# RecyclerView TextView color of text changed

Tags: android

Making some soccer app, I have few `Activities`, `Fragments` and `RecyclerViews`, but just in this one case colour of my text changed: 
[image]

The fragment is displaying logo and name appropriately.

But in `RecyclerView`, you can barely see name of players because it's so white, and 3 other small text are also hard to read.
It is looking like text changed it's color to fit to some black theme, while through my all app it is default `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

When editing everything looks fine:

[image]

and the code of one view holder also looks fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="12: Tyler Blackett"
        android:id="@+id/txt_players_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_players_position"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_players_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_players_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_players_name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_players_nationality"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_players_position"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_players_position"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_players_position" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_players_value"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_players_nationality"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_players_nationality"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_players_nationality" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Some code from Adapter. I am using this adapter multiple times (case 0,1,2) and only in this one case it is changing the color of text:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        switch(viewType){
            case 0:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_teams, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder0(view);
                break; //working fine
            case 1:
                {...} //working fine
            case 2:
                {...} //working fine
            case 3:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_players, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder3(view);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }
```

In onBind i just call .setText to TextView, nothing unusual there. 
Holder class:

```
public class ViewHolder3 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mPlayerName;
        TextView mPosition;
        TextView mNationality;
        TextView mValue;

        public ViewHolder3(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mPlayerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_players_name);
            mPosition = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_players_position);
            mNationality = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_players_nationality);
            mValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_players_value);
        }
```

Comment: Post the `getView()` method of your recyclerView. Most probably, you are passing `null` as the parent `ViewGroup` when inflating your XML layout.

Comment: Or... Just set the `android:textColor` attribute for your TextView in XML.

Comment: getView()? That's ListView thing. You mean onCreateViewHolder, i've edited post with more code. `android:textColor` is workaround, i want to know why am i getting this problem

Comment: Have you tried setting the text color of your TextView (Which you can also do from code) ?

Comment: I managed to change it with `android:textColor`. Thank you for your help. It could be some bug with AndroidStudio, really weird that same adapter is working in 3 situations, but just in this one it is changing color of text.

Comment: I posted it as an answer, so it would be nice to accept it :-)

Comment: I knew I can change color of text both programatically and in xml, but this weird issue appeared and i wanted to know if i did something wrong.

So problem is still there, and i will accept your answer later if noone joins conversation.

Comment: You could be doing something wrong. In ListView , if you inflate the view and pass null as the parent viewGroup, you could end up with a problem like this, but I'm not familiar with RecyclerView though.

Comment: OP Please mark Alvaro's answer as the right one. JonasCz's answer is not an answer, It's erasing the question. There is no reason to set textcolor for each of your textviews when you've already set the theme colour for your app. This final code is like this \n myAdapter = new MainRVAdapter(MainActivity.this,getData());

Comment: this project I was working on is lost somewhere, so I can't check it, but I'm pretty sure it was problem Alvaro pointed out, and it is accepted as answer. Thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and it was because I was using in the `RecyclerView` a `LayoutInflater` created with the `Context` of the `Application`, instead of the current `Activity`.

After changing it to create from the `Activity`, the `RecyclerView` colors went back to black.

Comment: I'd like this answer 100 times more if I could. thanks!

Comment: Ok man you got it! how come this happend because of this? any reason?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `android:textColor` attribute for your `TextView` in your XML layout. This will let you change the color of the text as needed.